# Flutter: error when looping through data within children array

Tags: flutter

```
List myList = [{"id":27,"name":"Horror"},{"id":9648,"name":"Mystery"},{"id":53,"name":"Thriller"}];

...

Container(
   child: Row(
      children: [
         for(var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++){
            Text("VALUE:" + myList[i]['name']),
         }   
      ],  
   ),  
),  

...
```

I get this error:

> A value of type Set Text can't be assigned to a variable of type
> 'Widget'.

So how can I display the data in text widgets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although for your exmple you just need to remove de brackets and it'll work:
there's a Widget for Lists: `ListView`, and if you want the items to be displayed horizontal, just need to set the Axis to work horizontally:

Your example:

```
Container(
   child: Row(
      children: [
         for(var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++)
            Text("VALUE:" + myList[i]['name']),          
      ],  
   ),  
),
```

With ListView:

**itemBuilder:** returns the Widget to be displayed in each iteration of the list. In your example `Text("VALUE:${myList[index]['name']}")`:

**itemCount:** as its name suggests, is the amount of items of the list to be displayed.

```
Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text("VALUE:${myList[index]['name']}");
        },
        itemCount: myList.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, // to display items horizontally
      )),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't know I could use a for loop without brackets. I also came across a for loop followed by triple dots and square brackets `for(var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++)...[ // code here ]`. Do you know what it means ?

Comment: the three dots are known as the spread operator, from Dart 2.3 and above is used to simplify the addition of elements in list, set an Map. In this case you can use both ways and it'll work the same